# How to fix "readlink: missing operand"?

Tags: bash, symlink, readlink

I am getting this error after typing `sudo apt autoremove` in terminal

```
readlink: missing operand
Try 'readlink --help' for more information.
stat: missing operand
Try 'stat --help' for more information.
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Pre-Invoke 'stat -c %Z $(readlink -f $(which opera)) > /tmp/opera.timestamp'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I don't know how to solve this.
Can anyone help me??

Thanks

Comment: Confirm `which opera` returns the path of `opera`. You might need to fix your `PATH` variable, or reinstall `opera`.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is only for questions about writing software. This is a better fit for [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/)... or possibly [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

readlink requires a file and $(which opera) returns nothing.  As @mkayaalp mentioned in the above, you need to either (re)install opera (if you haven't) or update the PATH so which can find the binary.

Comment: Thanks Allan and @mkayaalp! I had to reinstall opera and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mr Termy that suggested to run CLI "$ sudo touch /usr/local/bin/opera; sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/opera" and it works for me - great!

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=399359

Comment: This will create an empty file at `/usr/local/bin/opera` - this might not be what you want, as it doesn't solve the issue, if it's caused by PATH misconfiguration etc, and could result in more problems down the line